# Cannot shutdown old postmaster when upgrading to Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm upgrading to Postgres 9.2.2 (from 9.1.4). When I try to upgrade the DBs using:

```
pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/bin -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.2/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres91 -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get the following error message:

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking current, bin, and data directories                 ok

There seems to be a postmaster servicing the old cluster.
Please shutdown that postmaster and try again.
Failure, exiting
```

I've trying stopping the server, but cannot get the upgrade command to work. How to I shutdown the old postmaster?

Comment: If you started the `brew service` then shut it down with `brew services stop postgres`

Answer (score 13):

The `postmaster.pid` should be inside the previous version's `usr/local/var` folder. Simply renaming this file should solve the problem.

Comment: I've come across this problem a couple of times as well and this is a good answer.  Stopping all instances of postgres before upgrading ought to be pertinent as well

Answer (score 6):

In OS X Yosemite, after having installed PostgreSQL via Homebrew:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. If `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres/ stop` returns `No such process`, then you should `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`.

Comment: Also work after migrating from v.13 to v.14 on Big Sur

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, stop the PostgreSQL service before performing the upgrade. This will stop all instances of postgres regardless of the versions installed.

`service postgresql stop`

Comment: That was it. Forgot to stop postgres service before running `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` with `brew services stop postgresql` on my MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

On most unix systems you'll find a init script in `/etc/init.d` which you can use to start, restart, reload or stop unix services.

e.g.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

If this is not available you can use `pg_ctl stop`

e.g.

```
su - postgres
bash-3.1$ pg_ctl stop  # normal stop
bash-3.1$ pg_ctl stop -m s # smart stop
bash-3.1$ pg_ctl stop -m f # fast stop
bash-3.1$ pg_ctl stop -m i # immediate stop
```

More about `pg_ctl`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-ctl.html

**EDIT**
If you still get the error and you are sure the postmaster is no longer running (check with `sudo ps aux | grep "postmaster"` - should return one line only)  you still have the pid file after a unclean shutdown

Remove the pidfile
e.g.

```
> sudo -u postgres mv /var/lib/postgres/data-9.1/postmaster.pid /tmp
```

Comment: When I try `pg_ctl stop`, I get: `pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset`. BTW, no server seems to be running: `luciano$ ps auxwww | grep postgresluciano          995   0.0  0.0  2434892    548 s000  R+   10:42PM   0:00.00 grep postgres`.

Comment: grep for postmaster

Comment: Updated answer with further info

Comment: No luck: `sudo ps aux | grep "postmaster"`
`luciano         3101   0.0  0.0  2434892    548 s002  S+    9:12PM   0:00.00 grep postmaster`

Comment: Issue solved. See my answer.